# Modify Elements Content In given URL using Simple PHP Parser

Tags: php

Below is my code. PHP code

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$id=$_GET['id'];//Some URL like index.php
$dom = file_get_contents($id);
$html = file_get_html($id);
?>
<html lang="en" class="wide smoothscroll wow-animation">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Update Content</title>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Page Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="page_name" value="<?php echo $filename;?>" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
foreach($html->find('meta[name=keywords]') as $element) {
?>    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Meta Keyword</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="meta_keyword"><?php echo $element->content; ?></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php } 
    foreach($html->find('meta[name=description]') as $element) {
?>  
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Meta Description</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="meta_description"><?php echo $element->content; ?></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
     <?php } foreach($html->find('title') as $element) {?>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Title</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" value="<?php echo $element->innertext; ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php } foreach($html->find('h1') as $element) {?>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">H1</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="h1" value="<?php echo $element->innertext; ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php } foreach($html->find('h2') as $element) {?>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">H2</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="h2" value="<?php echo $element->innertext; ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php } foreach($html->find('h3') as $element) {?>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">H3</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="h3" value="<?php echo $element->innertext; ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php } foreach($html->find('h4') as $element) {?>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">H4</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="h4" value="<?php echo $element->innertext; ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php } foreach($html->find('h5') as $element) {?>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">H5</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="h5" value="<?php echo $element->innertext; ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php } foreach($html->find('h6') as $element) {?>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">H6</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="h6" value="<?php echo $element->innertext; ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <br/><br/>
  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="content_submit" type="button" style="color:#fff">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  </form>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

Refrence I used for this http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Here I can Get all HTML elements with that code.And I want to modify the Same HTML element with Updated Text.But I don't get any reference from anywhere.Please is my page screenshot.

[image]

If I change something in that h3 textbox it will change in about.php `<h3>New text</h3>` How can I do this If anyone knows the solution Please help me to get out of this problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you reduce your problem to a simple statement with a small amount of reproducible code?  Sounds like all you want is `<script>$(function() { $("#h3").val("xxx"); }</script>`.  Please read this [mcve]

Comment: I did not getting your question?

Comment: If I change some text in textbox corresponding to h3 tag.it will chang directly in about.php it will not happen lik as u answered

Comment: Can u please check the reference which I added in question.In that there will be a tab named modify HTML elements There thy specify How to change content inside div similarly I want to change content directly in specified page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show you for the first one $html->find('meta[name=keywords]'),You have to use a function __set from simplehtmldom, I am taking name of textarea as formss

```
foreach($html->find('meta[name=keywords]') as $element) {

$element->__set("content", "$_POST['formss']");

}
```

Please use different class or id for textarea, in a page there can be one meta keyword or title, but it can contain many h3 or h4 or h5. So use a `for` loop for that and it will make it easier for you. One more thing, why have you used 
    $dom = file_get_contents($id);
    $html = file_get_html($id);
two loading functions they will load the same thing and make your php execution slow.

Comment: May I know similarly how can I Set content for title

Comment: First get title in a variable as you have done, and then use innertext instead of content in __set function

Comment: If multiple H3 tags is present in the webpage how can i set content?? Is there any way to find nth h1 tag and set content

Comment: You can use find function like find("h3",n) where n is number of h3. remember that find function create an array and than save all dom element to their respective position for a web page

Comment: Do you have any refrence link for this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126015/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-kumar).

Comment: Use this like   $data = $html->find('h3',0);
$data->__set("innertext", "Aditya changed it");
echo $data;       Where 0 is first h3 and you can go for more like an array

Comment: Its showing fatal error call to a member function __set() on a non-object.